# Oracle count matching values based on group of values

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am trying to figure out how to count matching values based on a group of values.  Below is example of the table structure.  I am using 12c

```
Table 1                                        Table 2

id  term    course  course_num              course course_num equ_course equ_num       
1   201710  MATH    1020                    MATH   1020       MATH       2015                                            
1   201510  MATH    2015                    MATH   1020       MATH       101
1   201680  MATH    101                     MATH   101        MATH       1020
2   201380  ENGL    1010
```

What I need is a count of the repeated courses that a student took.  In the example student with an id of 1 took both MATH 1020, 101, and 2015.  Since in table 2 (the equivalence table) MATH 2015 and MATH 101 count as MATH 1020 the results should show the below.  The repeated column is the number of times they repeated a course.

```
id  term   course  course_num  repeated
1   201710 MATH    1020        3  
1   201510 MATH    2015        3 
1   201680 MATH    101         3
```

Comment: Why is the repeated count "2" and not "3"?

Comment: You are right it should be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Lets change the sample data to make it more complicated; rather than `MATH/1020` being equivalent to `MATH/2015` and `MATH/101` we can chain the equivalencies so that `MATH/1020` is equivalent to `MATH/2015` which is, in turn, equivalent to `MATH/101`. This makes it insufficient to simply join `Table2` to itself to merge the equivalencies as there can be a tree many layers deep. Instead, use a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c9c9/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( id, term, course, course_num ) AS
  SELECT 1, 201710, 'MATH', 1020 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 201510, 'MATH', 2015 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 201680, 'MATH',  101 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 201380, 'ENGL', 1010 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( course, course_num, equ_course, equ_num) AS
  SELECT 'MATH', 1020, 'MATH', 2015 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MATH', 2015, 'MATH',  101 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH equivalent_courses ( course, course_num, equ_course, equ_num ) AS (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( course ),
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( course_num ),
         equ_course,
         equ_num
  FROM   Table2
  START WITH ( course, course_num )
             NOT IN ( SELECT equ_course, equ_num FROM TABLE2 )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR equ_course = course
  AND        PRIOR equ_num    = course_num
)
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         PARTITION BY COALESCE( e.course, t.course ),
                       COALESCE( e.course_num, t.course_num )
       ) AS repeated
FROM   Table1 t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN equivalent_courses e
       ON ( t.course = e.equ_course AND t.course_num = e.equ_num )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c9c9/6/0)**:

```
| ID |   TERM | COURSE | COURSE_NUM | REPEATED |
|----|--------|--------|------------|----------|
|  2 | 201380 |   ENGL |       1010 |        1 |
|  1 | 201710 |   MATH |       1020 |        3 |
|  1 | 201510 |   MATH |       2015 |        3 |
|  1 | 201680 |   MATH |        101 |        3 |
```

Comment: MT0, thanks for your help!  I have one other question.  What would be the easiest way to not include the courses that are only repeated once?

Comment: @Withnoe Wrap the final `SELECT` block in a `SELECT * FROM ( <final select block> ) WHERE repeated > 1` [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c9c9/14).

Comment: MT0, I just realized that my equivalence table is more difficult than I thought.  There are also records in it that have the class values in the opposite fields.  For example math 1020 is equivalent to math 101 but there is also a record where math 101 is equivalent to math 1020.    Therefore, the code you suggested will not work right.  Do you have any other ideas?